# talk server (talkd) not working

Tags: gnome, messaging

A user on another machine on the same local network cannot call me with `talk`.

My `talk`:

```
alba@mac2011-manjaro% systemctl status talk
○ talk.service - Talk Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/talk.service; indirect; preset: di>
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2023-02-16 21:56:03 WET; 15min ago
   Duration: 3min 59.508s
TriggeredBy: ● talk.socket
       Docs: man:talkd(8)
             man:talk(1)
    Process: 3170 ExecStart=/usr/bin/talkd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3170 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 5ms

Feb 16 21:52:04 mac2011-manjaro systemd[1]: Started Talk Server.
Feb 16 21:56:03 mac2011-manjaro systemd[1]: talk.service: Deactivated successfu>

alba@mac2011-manjaro% systemctl status talk.socket
● talk.socket - Talk Server Activation Socket
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/talk.socket; enabled; preset: disa>
     Active: active (listening) since Thu 2023-02-16 21:43:51 WET; 28min ago
      Until: Thu 2023-02-16 21:43:51 WET; 28min ago
   Triggers: ● talk.service
       Docs: man:ta    alba@mac2011-manjaro% mesg
is y    alba@mac2011-    alba@mac2011-manjaro% mesg
is ymanjaro% mesg
is ylkd(8)
             man:talk(1)
     Listen: 0.0.0.0:518 (nslonslookup mach_namenslookup mach_namenslookup mach_namenslookup mach_nameokup mach_nameDatagram)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 19063)
     Memory: 8.0K
        CPU: 563us
     CGroup: /system.slice/talk.socket

Feb 16 21:43:51 mac2011-manjaro systemd[1]: Listening on Talk Server Activation

alba@mac2011-manjaro% mesg
is y
```

For the user on the other machine:

```
alba@mac2011-manjaro-1% talk alba@mac2011-manjaro
[Service connection established.]
[Your party is not logged on]
```

Each side has Manjaro Linux, Gnome desktop and only one terminal open.

What is wrong?

On the same local network with the same commands, Mac OS responds to `talk` from other Linux or Mac OS machines.

Maybe useful:

```
alba@mac2011-manjaro% who
alba     :1           2023-02-16 21:33 (:1)
alba@mac2011-manjaro% tty
/dev/pts/0
alba@mac2011-manjaro% w
 11:09:38 up 1 day, 13:36,  1 user,  load average: 1.54, 1.43, 1.33
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
alba     :1        Thu21   ?xdm?  22:21m  0.01s /usr/lib/gdm-x-session --run-sc
```

Comment: Maybe as written `talkd` does not consider Gnome terminal as being logged on.

Comment: In your terminal, does `who` return anything? If so, does the terminal device it lists match with the one you'll get by typing `tty`?

Comment: I am adding terminal info in question.  Another possible test is try talk while being logged on to a terminal outside Gnome.

Comment: The code to support `wtmp` in Gnome Terminal [was removed](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747046) in 2015

Comment: Indeed I have been able to receive talk call after starting in multi-user mode (no desktop environment).

Comment: `utmpdump /var/log/wtmp` still works.  It is a log file including terminal use.

Comment: `who` does not report Gnome terminals.  The problem can be seen by trying to talk from a desktop terminal to another.  By comparison, on Mac OS, `who` reports all terminal windows opened on the desktop and they can talk to eachother.